In my GoogleAppScript program the HTML2 is not capturing my document when sending to the Google Drive via Mobile Device
My web app is hosted on Google App Script and the purpose of it is to collect signatures and send the signed document to a designated Google Drive Folder. Essentially when I use a desktop or laptop to sign the document the program works as intended. The picture of the whole document is taken with the signature and filled out info and is sent to the Google Drive Folder. However when I lauch the web app on my phone and press send with the fields filled out the program sends a blank png file, with no screenshot. The web app is rendered and all the other functions work, it just does not send a picture of the signed document on mobile devices. I am assuming it has something to do with the HTML2 or the size of the canvas.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  <title>Liability From</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <h1> Liability form </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="margin"> </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="paper">
      <div id="app" class="container">
        <div class="margin text-center">
          <div class="canvas mx-auto">
            <h1> LIABILITY FROM </h1>
            <br>
            <p> Description</p>
          </div>
          <div id="messageContainer" class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;"> Signature sent successfully!
          </div>
          <br>
          <div id="checkboxContainer" class="checkbox">
            <span class="red-asterisk">*</span><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox"> <strong>I ACKNOWLEDGE </strong></label>
          </div>

          <div class="name-date">
            <div class="print-name">
              <label for="print-name"><span class="red-asterisk">*</span><strong>Name:</strong> </label>
              <input type="print-name" id="name" name="name" class="custom-border">
            </div>

            <div class="email-section">
              <label for="print-email"><span class="red-asterisk">*</span><strong>Email:</strong></label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="custom-border" class="validate">
            </div>

            <div class="date-section">
              <label for="date"><span class="red-asterisk">*</span><strong>Today's Date:</strong></label>
              <br>
              <input type="date" id="date" name="date" class="custom-border">
            </div>

          </div>

          <p> <strong> Signature: </strong> </p>
          <br>
          <canvas id="sig" width="700px" height="150px" class="border" style="cursor: crosshair;"></canvas>

          <div>
            <button type="button" class="pill" id="clearSig">Clear</button>

            <button type="button" class="pill" id="send">Send</button>
            <button type="button" class="pill" disabled id="load">
              <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              Sending...
            </button>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footerContainer">
    <p class="copyright">Form</p>
  </div>
</footer>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@4.0.0/dist/signature_pad.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="/src/Code.js"> </script>

<script>

  document.getElementById('load').style.display = 'none'
  let signaturePad;

  function setupSignatureBox() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("sig");
    signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
  }

  function clearSignature() {
    signaturePad.clear();
  }

  const sendToDrive = () => {
    try {
      const nameInput = document.getElementById("name").value.trim();
      const dateInput = document.getElementById("date").value.trim();
      const emailInput = document.getElementById("email").value.trim();
      let checkboxChecked = document.getElementById("checkbox").checked;

      let existingAlert = document.getElementById("errorAlert");
      if (existingAlert) {
        existingAlert.remove();
      }

      if (!checkboxChecked) {
        throw new Error('Please acknowledge the terms of the liability!');
      }

      if (!nameInput) {
        throw new Error('Please enter your NAME!');
      }

      if(!emailInput){
        throw new Error('Please enter your EMAIL ADDRESS!')
      }

      if (!dateInput) {
        throw new Error('Please enter today\'s DATE!');
      }

      if(signaturePad.isEmpty()){
        throw new Error('Please sign the document!');
      }

      const today = new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString()).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
      if (dateInput !== today) {
        throw new Error('Please enter TODAY\'S date!');
      }

      document.getElementById('send').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('load').style.display = 'inline';

      let mainContent = document.getElementById("app");
      mainContent.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";

      html2canvas(mainContent).then(function (canvas) {
        const imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function () {
          document.getElementById('messageContainer').style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById('load').style.display = 'none';
          setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById('messageContainer').style.display = 'none';
          }, 3000);
        }).recieveSignature(nameInput, emailInput, imageData);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      displayError(error.message);
    }
  }

  const displayError = (errorMessage) => {
    let alertDiv = document.createElement('div');
    alertDiv.className = 'alert alert-danger';
    alertDiv.id = 'errorAlert';
    alertDiv.textContent = errorMessage;

    let checkboxDiv = document.querySelector('.checkbox');
    checkboxDiv.parentNode.insertBefore(alertDiv, checkboxDiv);
  }

  document.getElementById("clearSig").addEventListener("click", clearSignature);
  document.getElementById("clearSig").addEventListener("touchend", clearSignature);
  document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", sendToDrive);
  document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("touchend", sendToDrive);
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setupSignatureBox);
</script>

</html>

JavaScript:
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
}

const recieveSignature = (nameInput,emailInput,encodedImage) => {
  const data = encodedImage.split(",")[1];
  const dataDecoded = Utilities.base64Decode(data);
  let fileName = (`${nameInput}_signed.png`)
  const signatureAsPictureBlob = Utilities.newBlob(dataDecoded).setName(fileName);
  DriveApp.getFolderById(GoogleDriveFolder).createFile(signatureAsPictureBlob);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailInput, 'Thanks for the submission!', 'Confirmation')
  return "Signature sent successfully!";
}


Have you tried different mobile browsers? For example, in some cases the behavior of Chrome and Firefox may differ. Then you can provide for checking the user agent.
